# Send Post request in Node js Rest API

Tags: node.js, rest, express

**I CAN'T SEND POST REQUEST FROM CLIENT SIDE !**

I need to send HTTP Post request in Node js Rest API to the payment gateway.
Post request needs to have headers and body payload. I have frontend and backend separated, I'm using Rest API with express.js and payment gateway needs server to server communication so I can't to do that from client side. Basically when user clicks on payment I need to send call to my backend server then my backend server needs to send request to the payment gateway.

Payment gateway has documentation with only MVC ( Model View Controller ) and they really can't help.

So logic inside controller should be something like this

```
exports.payment = (req, res, next) => {
   const { amount, id, currency } = req.body;

   //add headers
   //create body paloyad

   //send request to https://payment....com/api-key/transaction

   //receive response

   res.status(200).json({ status: 'success' });
}
```

Comment: What you are trying is called 'hooks' checkout these links below
1. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html 
2. https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-create-a-custom-react-hook-and-publish-it-to-npm/

Comment: Please read questions carefully

Comment: If i understand the question correctly what you are trying is 
1. client clicks Payment btn
2. POST req hits your backend server
3. your backend server inturn makes another POST req to payment gateway and send a delayed responce

Comment: That's right but I need to send POST request from node js rest api, not from react or in my case angular, It must go from rest api, I know how to send post request from browser there's no problem...

Comment: I think one step is missing here because in my experience and I did up to 5 integrations with different payments providers where client is running web ot mobile after you receive response you need to create or change the order status

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to do it, like Fetch, however, I prefer using **Axios**:

```
const axios = require('axios');

exports.payment = (req, res, next) => {
   const { amount, id, currency } = req.body;

   //add headers
   const options = {
      headers: {'X-Custom-Header': 'value'}
   };

   //create body payload
   const body = {
      amount: amount
      id: id
      currency: currency
   };

   //send request to https://payment....com/api-key/transaction
   axios.post('https://payment....com/api-key/transaction', body, options)
      .then((response) => {
        //receive response
        console.log(response);
        res.status(200).json({ status: 'success' });

      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
      });
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [Axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) to send POST requests. Its much easier.

```
const axios = require('axios')


let config = {
    headers: {
        header1: value,
    }
}

let data = {
 'amount': amount,
 'id':id,
 'currency':currency,
}


axios.post('https://payment....com/api-key/transaction', data,config)
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

const body = {a: 1};

const response = await fetch('https://httpbin.org/post', {
    method: 'post',
    body: JSON.stringify(body),
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
});
const data = await response.json();

console.log(data);
```